# Assistance with Access ADP and/or SQL iif statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, access-data-project

I'm using Access ADP as a front end to SQL. I have two tables:

- One is Price_2018
- One is Price_2020

I want to choose Price from the Price_2018 or the Price_2020 table, depending upon the Purchase_Date. I tried first putting IiF statement in the Query Designer:

```
Iif ([Purchase_Date] < Convert(DateTime, '2020-01-01 00:00:00'),[Price_2018],[Price_2020])
```

Access didn't allow that and ended up putting the whole thing in quotes in the SQL pane, so all I got was text output.

Someone suggested putting in the Select section:

```
CASE ([Purchase_Date] < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-01 00:00:00')   WHEN 1 THEN [Price_2018] ELSE [Price_2020]
```

That didn't work either and gave me this error:

```
Error in list of function arguments: '<' not recognized.Error in list of function arguments: ',' not recognized.Error in list of function arguments: 'FROM' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text.
```

### How to resolve this error. I'm not familiar with using a `CASE` statement in Access or SQL.

I combined 2 Price tables (combined table called VWC_2018_2020) as suggested. Full query:

```
SELECT      TOP 100 PERCENT dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Service_ID,                         dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Service_Date_From, dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Update_Status,                         dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Account_Number, dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Service_Units,                         dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Modifiers, dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Procedure_Code,                         NormalUnionCPASumAdjustments.SumAmount AS Adjustment, NormalUnionCPASumPayments.SumAmount AS Payment,                         dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Service_Fee AS Charge,                         dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Service_Fee - ISNULL(NormalUnionCPASumPayments.SumAmount, 0) AS Unpaid,                         dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Primary_Diagnosis_Code, LastInsurancePmt.last_insurance_pmt,                         dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Patient_Number, dbo.VWCFees_2018_2020.VWC_2020, dbo.VWCFees_2018_2020.VWC_2018,                        IIF (dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Service_Date_From < CDate('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),dbo.VWCFees_2018_2020.VWC_2018,dbo.VWCFees_2018_2020.VWC_2020) AS VWCFEE
FROM          dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo LEFT OUTER JOIN                        dbo.VWCFees_2018_2020 ON dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Procedure_Code = dbo.VWCFees_2018_2020.CPT LEFT OUTER JOIN                        dbo.NormalUnionCPASumAdjustments() NormalUnionCPASumAdjustments ON                         dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Service_ID = NormalUnionCPASumAdjustments.Service_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN                        dbo.NormalUnionCPASumPayments() NormalUnionCPASumPayments ON                         dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Service_ID = NormalUnionCPASumPayments.Service_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN                        dbo.LastInsurancePmt() LastInsurancePmt ON dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Service_ID = LastInsurancePmt.Service_ID
WHERE      (dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Update_Status <= 1) AND                         (dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Service_Date_From BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND                         (dbo.VHCSERVER_Ntier_VHC_dbo_vwGenSvcInfo.Patient_Number = @VHC_NumberChild)
```

Running in Access, gives error message: '<' not recognized.  Missing FROM clause.  Unable to parse query text.

What now? Thanks

Comment: ADP's are an excellent RAD (rapid application development) tool and it's a shame they have been deprecated. Are you able to create a view in your SQL database that does what you want. Then you can reference that in your ADP. It does sound like you have some data modelling issues but that's a bigger fish to fry

Comment: You should really have one Price table with year column for 2018 and 2020 values. And there is no `CASE` or `CONVERT` methods in Access SQL. Also, like any SQL expression, all tables need to be in query to use its columns. Please show full query with `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses (not line snippets).

Answer (score 0):

Since [ADP files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-access-project-89c48da0-55a4-45d4-9ee5-95f67383d4cb) use an SQL Server backend (no longer supported as of MS Access 2013), you must use its TSQL dialect which does support `IIF` (or `CASE`) and can compare dates with string representations without conversion.

Below I extend to fuller query assuming various columns. Adjust as needed:

```
SELECT
  ...
  IIF(t.[Purchase_Date] < '2020-01-01', p18.price, p20.price)
  ...
FROM [Transactions] t
INNER JOIN [Price_2018] p18
  ON t.price_id = p18.price_id
INNER JOIN [Price_2020] p20
  ON t.price_id = p20.price_id
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct for an ADP - Access Data Project. No data is actually stored using the JET engine. There are no linked tables as such - it's completely referencing a SQL Server database

Comment: Ah yes, I mistakenly conflated `accde` files, compiled executable versions of `accdb`. OP will then need to use TSQL dialect which as of SQL Server 2012 does support [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Edited accordingly.